# untrusted connection Show

Tags: connection

> Yesterday I have login into yahoo account but when I have pressed submit button the Untrusted connection message show. After this message yahoo mail page didn't open. Next day, again I have login into yahoo account by another ID then same message show. I can't understanding why this happening. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First check your account is activated or not. Have you got any
>   notification on your another mail account which you filled on
>   registration time on yahoo.